# Filter with Angular from Other Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the basic search in angular by filter.

```
  <input type="text" name="search_job" ng-model="search" />

<article ng-repeat="post in posts  | filter : filterObject |  filter : search ">
<h3><a href="#/post/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
<cite>by {{post.author}} on {{post.created_at | date}}</cite>
<p>{{post.body | limitTo:250}}..</p>
<a href="#/post/{{ posts.indexOf(post) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
```

I need to filter, from the other search in other page. So, I send the form by GET and toke it in PHP. I convert php variable in a window Javascript variable

```
window.myJsvar = <?=$_GET["word"]?>;
```

And, in app.js I put it in a $scope variable

```
app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json/jobs.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.filterObject = window.myJsvar;
    });
}])
```

But it not working. How can I do it?

Comment: Preferable to use either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: @KarthikVU Of course not. He should use a [**service**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Comment: Correct. I failed to notice he is using angular routes. The suggestion would be relevant if the was a page navigation.

Comment: Since you are angular routes, it's advisable to persist your data in an angular service, or you can bind your properties to the $rootScope.

Comment: I don't like to use localStorage for this action. Is very interesting your answer @Mistalis, I am going to study it because I didn't know about Services in AngularJS. Thanks.